# iPhone ASIHTTP error while uploading video file

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I am creating simple file uploaded. 
Some unexpected behavior is happening with File upload.

When i am running build from my iMac to iPhone, it works fine without any issue.
But when i create an build(ipa) file. and install it from iTune. Request fails.

Might be there is issue with ASIHTTP?

Comment: you should check proper memory management in you app.

Comment: any link you want want to share with me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can take idea from following code.

```
-(IBAction)btnPostData_Clicked: (id)sender
{
    NSString *file2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Ovation-Mike_Koenig-1061486511" ofType:@"mp3"];

    NSData *file1Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file2];

    NSURL *audiourl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://alligator.netsmartz.us/iphone/iphone.php"];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:audiourl];

    NSData *postData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file2];

    //SoundPath is your audio url path of NSDocumentDirectory.
    [request addData:postData withFileName:@"Ovation-Mike_Koenig-1061486511.mp3" andContentType:@"audio/mp3" forKey:@"company_audio"];

    [request setDelegate:self];

    [request startSynchronous];
}
```

Comment: thanks Luke and MSB but the issue is, when i make a build(ipa) to share with my client. its stops working.
there might be issue with ASIHTTP lib files. I am using XCODE 4.3.

Comment: what deployment target you set when you build the ipa?

Comment: Device : iPhone and Deployment Target : 4.0